# Is there a way to get the field names of a struct in a macro?

Tags: rust, macros

Consider the following example:

```
struct S {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}
```

I have a macro which is called like this:

```
my_macro!(S);
```

I want to access the field names of the struct in the macro like this:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($t:ty) => {{
        let field_names = get_field_names($t);
        // do something with field_names
    }};
}
```

I'm new to Rust and macros, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: One idea was to create a command line interface for the given struct using the macro. I wanted to deconstruct the struct and create appropriate options/flags based on the type of each field. However, while I'm talking about it now, I'm not sure if  macros are the best way to do this...

Comment: Well, maybe it's also possible to do that using just Generics and Traits.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A macro is expanded during parsing, more or less; it has no access to the AST or anything like that—all it has access to is the stuff that you pass to it, which for `my_macro!(S)` is purely that there should be a type named `S`.

If you define the struct as part of the macro then you can know about the fields:

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    (struct $name:ident {
        $($field_name:ident: $field_type:ty,)*
    }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($field_name: $field_type,)*
        }

        impl $name {
            // This is purely an example—not a good one.
            fn get_field_names() -> Vec<&'static str> {
                vec![$(stringify!($field_name)),*]
            }
        }
    }
}

my_macro! {
    struct S {
        a: String,
        b: String,
    }
}

// S::get_field_names() == vec!["a", "b"]
```

… but this is, while potentially useful, often going to be a dubious thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another possibility that does not require to write a macro (however, the field names will be resolved at run time):

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::{Encoder, Json};
use rustc_serialize::json::Json::Object;
use rustc_serialize::Encodable;

#[derive(Default, RustcEncodable)]
struct S {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut json = "".to_owned();
    {
        let mut encoder = Encoder::new(&mut json);
        S::default().encode(&mut encoder).unwrap();
    }

    let json = Json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
    if let Object(object) = json {
        let field_names: Vec<_> = object.keys().collect();
        println!("{:?}", field_names);
    }
}
```

(this solution needs the `rustc-serialize` crate)

The `derive(Default)` has been added to avoid having to manually create a struct as you wanted (but a struct will still be created).

This solution works by encoding the struct to a `String` in JSON format and decoding it to a `Json`. From the `Json` object, we can extract the field names (if it is an `Object` variant).

A possibly more efficient method is to write its own encoder:

```
struct FieldNames {
    names: Vec<String>,
}

impl FieldNames {
    fn new() -> FieldNames {
        FieldNames {
            names: vec![],
        }
    }
}

struct FieldsEncoder<'a> {
    fields: &'a mut FieldNames,
}

impl<'a> FieldsEncoder<'a> {
    fn new(fields: &mut FieldNames) -> FieldsEncoder {
        FieldsEncoder {
            fields: fields,
        }
    }
}

type EncoderError = ();

impl<'a> Encoder for FieldsEncoder<'a> {
    fn emit_struct<F>(&mut self, _name: &str, _len: usize, f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        f(self)
    }

    fn emit_struct_field<F>(&mut self, f_name: &str, _f_idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        self.fields.names.push(f_name.to_owned());
        Ok(())
    }

    type Error = EncoderError;
    fn emit_nil(&mut self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_usize(&mut self, _v: usize) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_u64(&mut self, _v: u64) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_u32(&mut self, _v: u32) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_u16(&mut self, _v: u16) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_u8(&mut self, _v: u8) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_isize(&mut self, _v: isize) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_i64(&mut self, _v: i64) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_i32(&mut self, _v: i32) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_i16(&mut self, _v: i16) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_i8(&mut self, _v: i8) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_bool(&mut self, _v: bool) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_f64(&mut self, _v: f64) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_f32(&mut self, _v: f32) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_char(&mut self, _v: char) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_str(&mut self, _v: &str) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_enum<F>(&mut self, _name: &str, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_enum_variant<F>(&mut self, _v_name: &str, _v_id: usize, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_enum_variant_arg<F>(&mut self, _a_idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_enum_struct_variant<F>(&mut self, _v_name: &str, _v_id: usize, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_enum_struct_variant_field<F>(&mut self, _f_name: &str, _f_idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_tuple<F>(&mut self, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_tuple_arg<F>(&mut self, _idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_tuple_struct<F>(&mut self, _name: &str, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_tuple_struct_arg<F>(&mut self, _f_idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_option<F>(&mut self, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_option_none(&mut self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_option_some<F>(&mut self, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_seq<F>(&mut self, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_seq_elt<F>(&mut self, _idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_map<F>(&mut self, _len: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_map_elt_key<F>(&mut self, _idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
    fn emit_map_elt_val<F>(&mut self, _idx: usize, _f: F) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> { Err(()) }
}
```

which can be used as such:

```
fn main() {
    let mut fields = FieldNames::new();
    {
        let mut encoder = FieldsEncoder::new(&mut fields);
        S::default().encode(&mut encoder).unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", fields.names);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do the same: access the field names of a struct. But with the added complication that the struct was already using a `#[derive()]` style macro, which is incompatible with [`macro_rules!` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29986760/2352071). As I expect my use case to be rather common, here's a quick write-down of my solution.

My ultimate goal was to write a `CSV` header line corresponding to a `struct Record` with the [`csv`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/) crate, even when no record is written (writing records is usually done via [`serialize()`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.serialize), but we sometimes filter all records and still want a valid empty `CSV` file as output). This exact problem has also been formulated in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37140768/2352071) and that [this is not possible with just the `csv` crate is a known and currently unresolved issue](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/issues/161).

My solution to the extra complication with the `#[derive()]` macro on the struct is to use the [`#[derive(FieldNamesAsArray)]` macro defined by the `struct-field-names-as-array` crate](https://docs.rs/struct-field-names-as-array/latest/struct_field_names_as_array/).

You need to define the dependency in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
struct-field-names-as-array = "0.1"
```

Then you can simply annotate the `struct Record` in your `something.rs` module with the respective derive macro and use the resulting constant `Record::FIELD_NAMES_AS_ARRAY` for header writing:

```rust
// csv-specific imports
use csv::WriterBuilder;
use serde::Serialize;

// import for getting the field names array
use struct_field_names_as_array::FieldNamesAsArray;

// Serialize from serde, to write `Record`s systematically
// FieldNamesAsArray to get the field names
#[derive(Serialize,FieldNamesAsArray)]
struct Record {
    field_1: String,
    field_2: u64,
}

// ensure that serializing records does not write a header with
// the `.has_headers(false)`
let mut csv_writer = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
    .has_headers(false)
    .from_path("foo.csv")?;

// Manually write out the header.
csv_writer.write_record(Record::FIELD_NAMES_AS_ARRAY)?;

// `serialize()` records later, if some condition is met.
// But we also have a correct header if this condition is never met.
if some_condition {
    csv_writer.serialize(Recor {
        field_1: "some_string",
        field_2: 71028743,
    })?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedural macro will return the fields of an annotated struct

```
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn;

#[proc_macro_derive(GetAttributesMacro)]
pub fn get_attributes_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Construct a representation of Rust code as a syntax tree
    // that we can manipulate
    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // Build the trait implementation
    impl_get_attributes(&ast)
}

fn impl_get_attributes(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    let name = &ast.ident;
    let fields = match ast.data {
        syn::Data::Struct(ref data) => match data.fields {
            syn::Fields::Named(ref fields) => fields.named.iter().map(|f| f.ident.clone().unwrap()),
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        },
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    };

    let gen = quote! {

    impl GetAttributesMacro for #name {
            fn get_attributes(&self) -> Vec<&str> {
             let mut vec = Vec::new();

                #(
                    vec.push(stringify!(#fields));
                )*
            return vec;
            }
        }
    };

    gen.into()
}
```

example:

```
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize, GetAttributesMacro)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Asset {
    pub id: String,
}
```

```
fn main() {
    let d = deployment::Asset {
        id: String::from("test"),
    };

    for i in v {
            println!("{}", i)
    }
}
```

```
   Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.17s
     Running `target/debug/proc`
id
```