# How to get struct field names in Rust?

Tags: reflection, rust, introspection

Is there some equivalent of JS's [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for Rust's [struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/structs.html)?

I need something to generate CSV headers (I use [rust-csv](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/csv/)) from structure field names.

```
struct Export {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    gender: String,
    date_of_birth: String,
    address: String
}

//... some code

let mut wrtr = Writer::from_file("/home/me/export.csv").unwrap().delimiter(b'\t');

wrtr.encode(/* WHAT TO WRITE HERE TO GET STRUCT NAMES as tuple of strings or somethings */).is_ok()
```

Comment: You can’t do that without a *rustc* plugin (works only on a nightly).

Comment: Thanks @mcarton. I'll read about [Compiler Plugins](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compiler-plugins.html).
I really like to keep certain data in one place, so using field's name could be great. And I could move to nightly, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely to need a compiler plugin for your actual usecase; can probably use `#[derive(RustcDecodable)]` as [described in the repository](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv). Doesn't answer the question you are asking though, which is a generic way to list **any** structs field names. My old friend, the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Now that I think of it, syntax plugins are expanded before type analysis, so it would be rather tricky even in a plugin. There is some starter doc in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compiler-plugins.html). You’d need a [macro](https://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/rustc_plugin/registry/struct.Registry.html) and maybe a custom attribute for the type to inspect.

Comment: @Shepmaster `#[derive(RustcDecodable)]` is a plugin :), but yeah, let’s not reinvent the wheel. Also serde is usually better.

Comment: @mcarton an interesting philosophical question: "Is a plugin that is always plugged-in still a plugin?" ^_^. But as you pointed out, the important thing is to reuse existing work and potentially avoid needing to use the nightly compiler. Serde even has stable support (via `build.rs`) for pre-processing "syntax extensions".

Comment: This can be also done by implementing your own procedural macro where you parse AST and create a trait implementation for your struct which returns the field names. I have done it personally 2 weeks ago but the code is not public and this question has already been closed. So just letting you know this is possible by some `#[derive(Introspection)]`.

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants I will make it public during a week. I may tell you here when it happens if you are interested in this solution (all it needs is just to add `#[derive(Introspection)]` to your enum or struct.

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants [here it is](https://github.com/vityafx/introspection). Hope this helps. I have not provide enough docs yet but you may already use it. I have plans for extending it's functionality in some future but somethings are just impossible to do :(

Comment: use serde_aux::prelude::*; See the usage example [serde-aux](https://docs.rs/serde-aux/latest/serde_aux/serde_introspection/fn.serde_introspect.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The current main method of metaprogramming in Rust is [via macros](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/macros.html). In this case, you can capture all the field names and then add a method that returns string forms of them:

```
macro_rules! zoom_and_enhance {
    (struct $name:ident { $($fname:ident : $ftype:ty),* }) => {
        struct $name {
            $($fname : $ftype),*
        }

        impl $name {
            fn field_names() -> &'static [&'static str] {
                static NAMES: &'static [&'static str] = &[$(stringify!($fname)),*];
                NAMES
            }
        }
    }
}

zoom_and_enhance!{
struct Export {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    gender: String,
    date_of_birth: String,
    address: String
}
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Export::field_names());
}
```

For advanced macros, be sure to check out [*The Little Book of Rust Macros*](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/README.html).

Comment: Similar question and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29986760/996886

Comment: @melak47 good point! Do you think that this question should be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: can you enhance it..? hold on, I'll enhance it.

Comment: It seems like I can't add an answer here, so I did over at the other linked question. My added complication was that I also needed `#[derive()]` macros to work on the struct, so the solution here was incompatible with that. My write-down of a workaround is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73375434/2352071