# Is it possible to iterate over an external struct's members in a macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm working on a Rust app that needs to compile for WebAssembly, which means exposing quite a lot of internal & external structs for use from TypeScript.  I want to write a macro to automate this job as it's quite tedious.

I want is a macro `wasm_wrap_type!(WasmStruct, ExternalCrateStruct)` which produces a struct with the `wasm_bindgen` attribute called `WasmStruct` that implements all the public methods of `ExternalCrateStruct` (and added JavaScript getters & setters for properties).

I know that libraries like serde iterate over members using a `derive` macro, but I don't think that's possible to use in this situation.

My end goal is that calling this:

```
wasm_wrap_type!(WasmStruct, ExternalCrateStruct)
```

Generates this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct WasmStruct(ExternalCrateStruct);

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl WasmStruct {

    // For each member of ExternalCrateStruct...
    #[wasm_bindgen(setter)]
    pub fn member(&self) -> TypeOfSetter {
        &self.0.member
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn set_member(&mut self, new_value: TypeOfSetter) {
        self.0.member = new_value;
    }

    // For each ecsFunction of ExternalCrateStruct...
    pub fn ecsFunction(&self, args...) -> ReturnType? {
        self.0.ecsFunction(args...)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate over the member and public functions of a struct defined in a separate crate?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: See also [How to introspect all available methods and members of a Rust type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39266001/155423)